# Skyrim SE Frostfall + Campfire Problem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, mods

I have a problem with Skyrim SE. I recently uninstalled and reinstalled the game because of SKSE malfunctioning, so now I use it without SKSE. However, I have also reinstalled my mods. Now, for some reason, whenever I load up my back-up save (before SKSE), the Campfire mod errors out and says that Frostfall is outdated or something similar. The error message also repeats every couple of seconds and whenever I try to save, Skyrim SE CTD's.

The thing is, I DO NOT have Frostfall installed before I got SKSE.

I have tried absolutely everything that comes to mind, such as uninstalling/reinstalling Campfire, installing Frostfall (thinking something was missing), and even reinstalling Skyrim SE. However, this weird error is still here. And yes, I HAVE sorted my load order using LOOT and have cleaned both my master files and Campfire using SSEEdit

Load order:

```
 0  0 Skyrim.esm
 1  1 Update.esm
 2  2 Dawnguard.esm
 3  3 HearthFires.esm
 4  4 Dragonborn.esm
 5  5 unofficial skyrim special edition patch.esp
 6  6 BSAssets.esm
 7  7 BSHeartland.esm
 8  8 BSPatchSE.esp
 9  9 arnima.esm
10  a RSkyrimChildren.esm
11  b Campfire.esm
12  c Falskaar.esm
13  d SMIM-SE-Merged-All.esp
14  e oblivious horses (ess stam speed) (dg ready).esp
15  f star_triple_gold_sepc_sp0ckrates.esp
16 10 star_spellswords_sepc_sp0ckrates.esp
17 11 star_knights_sepc_sp0ckrates.esp
18 12 50 more perk points.esp
19 13 Better Horses 3.0.esp
20 14 Book Covers Skyrim.esp
21 15 Helgen Reborn.esp
22 16 Eli_Breezehome.esp
23 17 get_seriously_overstocked_merchants_sepc_sp0ckrates.esp
24 18 practice dummies.esp
25 19 DiverseDragonsCollectionSE.esp
26 1a Footprints.esp
27 1b Hothtrooper44_ArmorCompilation.esp
28 1c Holidays.esp
29 1d Whistle.esp
30 1e Hothtrooper44_Armor_Ecksstra.esp
31 1f DrSKnapsacks.esp
32 20 Runandwalkpaces.esp
33 21 WondersofWeather.esp
34 22 Chesko_WearableLantern.esp
35 23 HearthfireMultiKid.esp
36 24 HearthfireMultiKid_LastName.esp
37 25 insects begone - spiders.esp
38 26 Point The Way.esp
39 27 TheScarlett.esp
40 28 The Haven From The Cold And Dark.esp
41 29 Skyrim Better Roads and Bridges - All In One - Merged.esp
42 2a Run For Your Lives.esp
43 2b Cloaks.esp
44 2c RiversideLodge.esp
45 2d inigo.esp
46 2e Cloaks - Dawnguard.esp
47 2f Cloaks - USSEP Patch.esp
48 30 Immersive Patrols II.esp
49 31 Complete Pack.esp
50 32 immersive wenches.esp
51 33 Populated Cities Towns Villages Legendary.esp
52 34 ScopedBows.esp
53 35 SofiaFollower.esp
54 36 get_no_dead_followers_sepc_sp0ckrates.esp
55 37 Provincial Courier Service.esp
56 38 notice board.esp
57 39 ForgottenCity.esp
58 3a The Paarthurnax Dilemma.esp
59 3b j3x-autocrossbows.esp
60 3c excalibursword.esp
61 3d npc ejector force.esp
62 3e giftsofakatosh.esp
63 3f apocalypse - magic of skyrim.esp
64 40 insects begone - chaurus.esp
65 41 RSChildren - Complete.esp
66 42 RSChildren_PatchUSSEP.esp
67 43 ScopedBows_ArrowTweaks.esp
68 44 Shout.esp
69 45 Vivid WeathersSE.esp
70 46 Vivid WeathersSE - Winter.esp
71 47 wetandcold.esp
72 48 IcePenguinWorldMap.esp
73 49 ScopedBows_EagleEyeTweak.esp
74 4a LrsamwaysExpandedSkyrimWeaponry.esp
75 4b When Vampires Attack.esp
76 4c Immersive Citizens - AI Overhaul.esp
77 4d Relationship Dialogue Overhaul.esp
78 4e RealisticWaterTwo.esp
      SkyHUD.esp
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a non-SE save with SE?

Comment: Nope, I do not own Oldrim. I started playing SSE about 7 months ago.

Comment: You have about 80 mods.  It's one of them...

Answer (score 1):

So I had this problem, for anyone else interested.

I uninstalled (i.e. deleted the .pex's and the .dll's and everything else) SKSE64 itself.  Then I reinstalled it.  This seemed to fix it.  Loading a save from before I loaded Campfire/Frostfall (I loaded it mid-game) before going back to my most recent save also maybe helped.

Also there's a couple of threads about fixing Frostfall/Campfire SE until SKSE64 is fixed and Frostfall is completely patched:

https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/4983030-frostfall-hypothermia-camping-survival/page-111#entry55366233  (look earlier in the thread for more advice)

https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/75jdkh/a_full_guide_to_fixing_frostfallcampfire_in_sse/